# How to find duplicates in two lists that are opposite values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel I have a table with fixtures and results. Essentially, `id1` and `id4` are both the same fixture as each team only plays once.

I am trying to figure out how to mark that as a duplicate with a formula to purge a list of thousands of results and fixtures.

| id | hometeam | goalsfor | goalsagainst | awayteam |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Team1 | 1 | 0 | Team6 |
| 2 | Team2 | 1 | 1 | Team5 |
| 3 | Team3 | 0 | 1 | Team4 |
| 4 | Team6 | 0 | 1 | Team1 |

I tried using (individually and combined) concatenate, COUNTIF and VLOOKUP, but I can't seem to figure how to do it to get the correct result.

How would I mark id4 as a duplicate of `id1`?

**Note**: I know there are duplicates. I created a list concat `hometeamvsawayteam` and found duplicates within that list, removed them and then concat `awayteamvshometeam` and found the duplicates in there and removed them. Then I applied a highlight duplicates to both columns and there were several duplicates.

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a formula like that (in G2):

```
=IFNA(LET(data,$B$2:$E$5, data0,SUBSTITUTE(data," ",""), lr,LAMBDA(r,CONCAT( r)), a,BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(data0,4,3,2,1),lr), b,BYROW(data0,lr),XMATCH(a,b)), "No")
```

The formula presents `id` (row number in data) of duplicates, or `No` if there is no duplicate.
[image: Duplicates]

Comment: I can't get this to fill down, it first gave me a fill error, so I made sure the cells were clear. But its only populating G2 after that. Tried Ctrl+Shift+Enter as I thought it was an array forumal, but that isn't working either

Comment: This is a dynamic formula. It doesn't need to be copied, it will return the result as an array. All you have to do is enter the appropriate range of cells into the formula in the `data` place. It will work in Excel 365.